# Pyspark: TaskMemoryManager: Failed to allocate a page: Need help in Error Analysis

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am facing these errors while running a spark job in standalone cluster mode.

My spark job aims at:

- Running some `groupby`,
- `count`,
- and `joins` to get a final `df` and then `df.toPandas().to_csv()`.

Input dataset is of 524 Mb. Error I get:

> WARN TaskMemoryManager: Failed to allocate a page (33554432 bytes), try again.

After multiple times repeating the above , again new error

1. WARN NettyRpcEnv: Ignored failure: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Cannot receive any reply in 10 seconds
2. org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeoutException: Futures timed out after [10 seconds]. This timeout is controlled by spark.executor.heartbeatInterval
3. at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout. org$apache$spark$rpc$RpcTimeout$$createRpcTimeoutException
4. ExecutorLostFailure (executor driver exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Executor heartbeat timed out after 158295 ms
5. Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 49128)
   Traceback (most recent call last):

   File "/home/stp/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/accumulators.py", line 235, in handle
   num_updates = read_int(self.rfile)
   File "/home/stp/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 545, in read_int
   raise EOFError
   EOFError
6. At last ###********##

   py4j.protocol.Py4JNetworkError: An error occurred while trying to connect to the Java server (127.0.0.1:38073)

On first thought , i assumed, the error might be due to memory error(TaskMemoryManager) and from Total 16gb, the process was consuming max 6 gb, leaving 9+gb free. Also I had set the driver memory as 10G. so Pass.

But, when I do a count() or show() on my final dataframe, it was a success op. But while doing toCsv, it is throwing the above errors/Warnings.

Don't actually understand/guess what might be causing the issue.

Please help me analyzing the above errors. Any help/comment is welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 20):

In our case, we had lot of smaller tables (< 10 MB). So we decided to disable the broadcast and in addition to that started using G1GC for garbage collection. Add these entries to you spark-defaults.conf file in $SPARK_HOME/conf

```
spark.driver.extraJavaOptions -XX:+UseG1GC
spark.executor.extraJavaOptions  -XX:+UseG1GC
spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold    -1
```

Or as an alternative you can adjust the threshold size for autoBroadcast and see it that solves the issue.

Comment: Worth to analyze the table size in join and take appropriate actions. For some it might not work. But, worked for me.

Comment: New to spark, could you explain a bit what these various options are doing? Ie. what issues they are intended to address?

Comment: Found this useful: https://github.com/vaquarkhan/vaquarkhan/wiki/Apache-Spark--Shuffle-hash-join-vs--Broadcast-hash-join

Comment: This worked for me too with local mode and two small dataset

Comment: This really saved my day. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been handled offically in this Spark ticket https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-33032.

I just had the same issue and the correct solution was to increase my spark.driver.memory to a way larger size (e.g. 10GIG).

Every broadcast has to be sent through the driver, so it makes sense, that troubles arise, if the broadcast significantly blocks the drivers memory.